# why python statistics.mean() return an int type, not float

Tags: python, numpy

I use statistics.mean() to calculate mean from sampled distribution. However, in the following code, the returned value from the following value is rounded integer. If I use numpy.mean() instead, will get the correct float typed results. So what is going on here?

```
import statistics
from scipy import stats

posterior_sample = stats.beta.rvs(3, 19, size = 1000)
predictive_sample = stats.binom.rvs(100, posterior_sample, size = 1000)
print(statistics.mean(predictive_sample))
print(statistics.mean([(data >= 15).astype(int) for data in predictive_sample]))
```

Comment: A simpler example: `statistics.mean([6, 7, 8, 9])` and `statistics.mean(np.array([6, 7, 8, 9]))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`statistics.mean` does not support the `numpy.int64` data type.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) for `statistics`:

> Unless explicitly noted otherwise, these functions support int, float,
>   decimal.Decimal and fractions.Fraction. Behaviour with other types
>   (whether in the numeric tower or not) is currently unsupported. Mixed
>   types are also undefined and implementation-dependent. If your input
>   data consists of mixed types, you may be able to use map() to ensure a
>   consistent result, e.g. map(float, input_data).

To get around this, you can do as suggested, and convert your data to `float` before passing to `statistics.mean()`.

```
print(statistics.mean(map(float, predictive_sample)))
```

**Now for the underlying reason behind this behaviour:**

At the end of the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/statistics.py) for `statistics.mean`, there is a call to `statistics._convert`, which is meant to convert the returned value to an appropriate type (i.e. Fraction if inputs are fractions, `float` if inputs are `int` etc).

A [single line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/statistics.py#L243) in `_convert` is meant to catch other data types, and ensure that the returned value is consistent with the provided data (`T` is the data type for each input value, `value` is the calculated mean):

```
try:
    return T(value)
```

If your input is `numpy.int64`, then the `_convert` function tries to convert the calculated mean to `numpy.int64` data type. NumPy happily converts a float to an int (rounded down I think). And hence the `mean` function returns a mean rounded to the nearest integer, encoded as `numpy.int64`.

If your input data is `numpy.float64`, then you won't have this problem.